# Passing multiple subnet ids to a different module in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to pass multiple subnets in my Vnet to the Keyvault. What I'm looking for is on how to pass the subnet ID's to KeyVault module. Please find my code below;

**Variables.tf**

```
# Subnets

    subnet = {
    "subnet1" = {
        name = "subnet1"
        address_prefixes = [""]
        route_table_name = ""
    },
    "subnet2" = {
        name = "subnet2"
        address_prefixes = [""]
        route_table_name = ""
    },
    "subnet3" = {
        name = "subnet3"
        address_prefixes = [""]
        route_table_name = ""
       },
    },
```

**Main.tf**

```
module "key_vault" {
 source = "./../resource_modules/key_vault"
            
# init
tenant_id = var.tfvars.tenant_id
            
# rg
key_vault_rg_name = var.region.key_vault_rg_name
location          = var.region.location
            
# key vault
key_vault        = var.region.key_vault
key_vault        = var.tfvars.key_vault
spn_object_id    = var.tfvars.spn_object_id
            
virtual_network_subnet_ids = module.subnet.subnet_id
            
}
    
    
    module "subnet" {
      source   = "./modules/subnet"
      for_each = var.region.subnet
    
      network_rg = var.region.network_rg
      location   = var.region.location
    
      route_table_id = module.route_table[each.value.route_table_name].id
    
      region    = each.value
      vnet_name = module.vnet.vnet_name
    }
```

**Subnet.tf**

```
        resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
          resource_group_name  = var.netrg_name 
          name                 = var.region.name
          address_prefixes     = var.region.address_prefixes
          virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
        
          enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = 
          var.region.enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies
        }
```

**Keyvault.tf**

```
        resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
          resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
          location                        = var.location
          tenant_id                       = var.tenant_id
        
          name                            = var.key_vault.name
          sku_name                        = var.key_vault.sku
          enabled_for_disk_encryption     = var.key_vault.disk_encryption_enabled
          soft_delete_retention_days      = var.key_vault.retention
          purge_protection_enabled        = var.key_vault.purge_protection
          enabled_for_template_deployment = var.key_vault.enabled_for_template_deployment
          enabled_for_deployment          = var.key_vault.enabled_for_deployment
        
          network_acls {
            default_action = var.key_vault.acl_default_action
            bypass         = var.key_vault.acl_bypass
            ip_rules       = [""]
        
            virtual_network_subnet_ids = var.virtual_network_subnet_ids
          }
        }
```

How can I pass the output values from Subnet module (5 subnet in total=5 id's) to Keyvault module? I'm new to terraform and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you defined a corresponding subnet output in the Subnet module?

Comment: @MarkoE no i haven't. Do i need to?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things required based on the code you have:

1. Define an output in the Subnet module
2. Use the same variable name when passing the values to the Key Vault module as the one you have defined in the module. For example, in the module you have `var.vnet_subnet_ids` but when calling the module you commented out `#virtual_network_subnet_ids = module.subnet.subnet_id`.
3. Make sure you are using the correct argument in the `azurerm_key_vault` resource. You are currently defining it as `vnet_subnet_ids` but the correct argument name is actually `virtual_network_subnet_ids` [1]:

```
  network_acls {
    default_action = var.key_vault.acl_default_action
    bypass         = var.key_vault.acl_bypass
    ip_rules       = [""]

    # This is the wrong argument name ---> vnet_subnet_ids = var.vnet_subnet_ids
  }
```

What I would do first is rename the variable to use the properly defined one, e.g.,:

```
vnet_subnet_ids = [module.subnet.subnet_id]
```

Make sure to set the variable type in the Key Vault module to be of type `list(string)`.

The second step would then be to define an output in the Subnet module:

```
output "subnet_id" {
  description = "Subnet IDs values."
  value       = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
}
```

The last step then is to fix the argument in the Key Vault module:

```
network_acls {
  default_action = var.key_vault.acl_default_action
  bypass         = var.key_vault.acl_bypass
  ip_rules       = [""]

  virtual_network_subnet_ids = var.vnet_subnet_ids
}
```

Please make sure you also understand how to use module outputs [2].

**EDIT**: As per the comments section, the requirement is to create multiple subnets using the Subnet module. As there is already a variable used with `for_each` the changes that have to happen are:

1. Add a variable in the Subnet module which will be used with `for_each`.
2. Pass the values from the already defined variable in the root module to the Subnet module.

```
module "subnet" {
  source    = "./modules/subnet"
  subnets   = var.region
  vnet_name = module.vnet.vnet_name
}
```

In the module, here is the change that has to happen:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  for_each             = var.region
  resource_group_name  = var.netrg_name 
  name                 = each.value.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
        
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = 
          each.value.enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies
}
```

Last but not the least, the output would be changed to:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  description = "Subnet IDs values."
  value       = values(azurerm_subnet.subnets)[*].id
}
```

In the root module, the change would be:

```
vnet_subnet_ids = module.subnet.subnet_ids
```

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/key_vault#virtual_network_subnet_ids

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs#declaring-an-output-value

Comment: sorry but which variable do i define as list(string) in the keyvault module? The variable "virtual_network_subnet_ids"? Also would this loop over all the subnet ids? as I'm not using for each here

Comment: The variable you would define in the Key Vault module, i..e, `vnet_subnet_ids`. The `azurerm_subnet` resource only returns one ID, hence one ID is shown in the answer.

Comment: But your current code has only one.

Comment: yes but I want to pass more than 1 and can't figure how to. I only havve ideas of using mapping. Can you give a hint if you know?

Comment: Well, that's a different question. But, I would probably use `for_each` or `count`. In that case, the output would have to be changed.

Comment: But you don't have multiple subnets. How would I change the answer if you don't know how many you want?

Comment: This will create multiple module instances but each will still have only one subnet per module.

Comment: The question is: do you want multliple subnets per module call?

Comment: Yes i want multiple subnets per module call

Comment: I have updated the answer. However, a lot of details are missing. For example, you have added only a part of the `region` variable to the question. You have also omitted the part where the route table is created, so I don't know where or how to adjust the variable for whatever resource it is being used.